# Is there an $SL_n$-invariant functional on the space of rational functions on the projective space $\mathbb P^{n-1}$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, geometric-invariant-theory

Let the group $SL_n$ act on the projective space $\mathbb P^{n-1}$ in the standard way (both defined over $\mathbb C$).

Is there an $SL_n$-invariant (linear) functional on the space of rational functions on  $\mathbb P^{n-1}$?

How to describe the space of all such functionals?

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}$ For $n=2$ it doesn't exist. For $n\geq 3$ it does. Let $P$ be any irreducible polynomial with trivial stabilizer in $G:=SL_n(\C)$. Let $K$ be the function field of the variety given by the equation $P=0$. Then there is a $K$- valued point $x_0$ in $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ with a trivial stabilizer. Let $X$ be the $G$- orbit of $x_0$ (just as a set). We can choose a local parameter at every point $x\in X$ in a $G$-equivariant way. Now every rational function $f$ can be expanded in every point $x \in X$ as a power series with coefficients say $a_k(f,x)\in K$. Take $\varphi(f)=\sum_{x\in X} a_{-1}(f,x)$. This is a non-trivial $K$- valued $G$-invariant functional on rational functions. Composing $\varphi$ with some $\C$-linear map $K\to \C$ will produce the desired functional.

EDIT: It shouldn't be a local parameter at every $x$, it should be $k-1$ of them. Anyway, one can expand rational functions in several variables into power series and extract coefficients, so one can construct lots of functionals like this.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I have some follow up questions:
1. Why is it true that for n=2 there is no such functional?

Comment: 2. Why is there $x_0$ as above?

Comment: 3. As you mentioned one can not just take a_{-1} if n>2. one has to take some combination of the coefficients of the taylor expansion of $f$ at x. not any combination will do. one has to choose a combination which is invariant w.r.t. change of coordinates. I do not see why there is such a combination (except for the trivial one $a_0$, which is not good because then the sum will be infinite), it looks as a problem similar to the previous one but in one dimension less. This could have given a proof by induction, but for this it  has to work also for $n=2$.

Comment: 4. it seems that you are using the fact that f is regular in all points of X except for finitely many. why is it true?

Comment: 5. rational functions on \P^{n-1} are the same as rational functions on \A^{n} of homogeneous degree 0. any such function can be pulled back to $\A^{n+1}$ under the projection. Thus we have an embedding of  the space of rational functions on $\P^{n-1}$ to  the space of rational functions on $\P^{n}$ . This gives, for any  $SL_{n+1}$ -invariant (linear) functional on the space of rational functions on $P^n$ a $SL_{n}$ -invariant (linear) functional on the space of rational functions on $P^{n-1}$.Thus we can use the construction for n=3 and get a construction for n-2. will we  get nesserly $0$?

Comment: 1. On $\P^1$ you can use a partial fraction decomposition to see if such functional $\chi$ exist it must be non-trivial on polynomials. But any polynomial $f$ can be written as $f(x)=p(x+1)-p(x)$ for some polynomial $x$. So $\chi(f)=\chi(p(x+1))-\chi(p)=0$.

Comment: 2. By definition, $K$ is the field of functions of the hypersurface $P(t_0,\cdots,t_n)=0$. So it contains the functions $y_0=t_0/t_n$, $y_1=t_1/t_n$,...,$y_{n-1}=t_{n-1}/t_n$ satisfying equation $P(y_0,\cdots,y_{n-1}, 1)=0$. The point $x_0$ is the point with coordinates $(y_0,\ldots,y_{n-1},1)$. Homogeneous polynomials with $\C$-coefficients vanishing at $x_0$ are precisely polynomials divisible by $P$. So if $P$ has trivial stabilizer, $x_0$ also has a trivial stabilizer.

Comment: 3. Since $x_0$ has trivial stabilizer, you don't need to worry about invariance w.r.t. change of coordinates. Choosing local coordinates at $x_0$, for any point $x$ of the orbit of $x_0$ there is **unique** element $g\in G$ such that $g(x_0)=x$. So you obtain local coordinates around $x$ by translating by $g$. So this is automatically $G$-invariant.

Comment: 4. As pointed out in 3. polynomials vanishing at $x_0$ are necessarily divisible by $P$. So for any homogeneous polynomial with $\C$-coefficients there is only finitely many elements of $X$ at which $P$ vanishes.

Comment: 5. We get $0$ functional because functions on $\P^{n}$ appearing by pullback from $P^{n-1}$ have polar divisor invariant under scaling, i.e. never has trivial stabilizer, but my $P$ is chosen so that it has trivial stabilizer.